# Translation of "der Richtschein"

Tags: translation, single-word-request, noun, german-to-english

I'm doing an internship in Germany in a steel-selling firm, and I'm struggling to translate the word *Richtschein* for my report. In the process of selling, that's what comes between the order (*Auftrag*) and the delivery note (*Lieferschein*).

My co-workers told me that it was equivalent to *Arbeitsschein*, *Rüstschein*, oder *Kommissionierschein*, but couldn't tell me any translation. Can anyone here help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your co-worker is correct (it would be Rüstschein though).
The translation would be

> pick list

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful ! I will edit my question for *Rüstschein*

Comment: It could still be Richtschein, right? The verb _richten_ can mean _to prepare for sending out_.

Comment: Yes, Richtschein is correct. (My comment in the answer addressed a typo in the question.) Depending on the process implemented, the proposed quasi-synonyms take different meanings, as @Thorsten Dittmar shows in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Dynamics NAV tells me that the report for the German word "Arbeitsschein" is "Work Order".

Please note that *Arbeitsschein*, *Rüstschein* and *Kommissionierschein* all have slightly different connotations:

*Arbeitsschein* is used in production environments and contains a list of steps to be performed to fulfill an order from a production point of view.

*Rüst-/Richtschein* is usually used if stuff created in production needs to be assembled to fulfill an order. It is similar to *Kommissionierschein*, only that there is some sort of pre-assembly taking place.

*Kommissionierschein* is used if ready-made equipment needs to be picked from storage and be packaged.